# Fetch data from web API working in the browser but not working in the device ionic app

Tags: http, web-services, ionic4, webapi

I build ionic app project and fetch data from SQL server using web API. The project working in the  browser but not working in the device.

Here the code:

```
synAccountFromServer() {
    this.dataServices.getAccountFromServer().subscribe(
      d => {
        alert('Data Success');
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error11: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    );


getAccountFromServer() {
    //alert('start get Datat from serve');   
    return this.http.get(this.urlGetAccounts);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is because you are using `http` not `https` in the source.

Check the value of `this.urlGetAccounts` has `https` at the start.

If it does then it's probably a CORS issue, which is not an Ionic problem. It requires your server with the web api to be configured differently.

Comment: Thanks . Itis worked . But you should to edit the IIS configuration to Https

Comment: Great, if that solved it then I would appreciate you marking it as the answer